# How to query s3 using select

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-s3-client

I have the following set up in the gradle

```
   implementation(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.18.25"))
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:s3")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client")
```

my code is as follows:

```
S3Client client = S3Client.builder()
        .region(Region.of("eu-west-1"))
        .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx")))
        .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder().buildWithDefaults(
                AttributeMap.builder().put(TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES, Boolean.TRUE).build()))
        .build();
```

And im trying to make a query request

```
SelectObjectContentRequest request = SelectObjectContentRequest.builder()
.bucket(bucket)
.key(key)
.expression(query)
.expressionType(ExpressionType.SQL)
        .build();
```

here is where i am stuck, as im not sure which s3 client i should use. I have been using the above client - S3Client.builder. But that does not have any method that takes in SelectObjectContentRequest as a request object.

Do i need to change the client, to AmazonS3 client AmazonS3ClientBuilder??
I am using the v2 of the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

please look at
https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html

```
default CompletableFuture<Void>
selectObjectContent(Consumer<SelectObjectContentRequest.Builder> selectObjectContentRequest, SelectObjectContentResponseHandler asyncResponseHandler)
```

*This action filters the contents of an Amazon S3 object based on a simple structured query language (SQL) statement.
default CompletableFuture*

```
selectObjectContent(SelectObjectContentRequest selectObjectContentRequest, SelectObjectContentResponseHandler asyncResponseHandler)
```

*This action filters the contents of an Amazon S3 object based on a simple structured query language (SQL) statement.*

[Fetching specific fields from an S3 document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67315601/fetching-specific-fields-from-an-s3-document)